# Django filters, set value

Tags: python, django, filter

I have code:

```
import django_filters

class BasicFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MyDataModel
        fields = []

class SiteFilter(BasicFilter):
    name = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=MySiteModel.objects.all(), help_text=''
    )
    class Meta(ReportFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['name']
```

And I need to get (in SiteFIlter) only records with user=request.user. Something like this:

```
class SiteFilter(BasicFilter):
    name = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=MySiteModel.objects.filter(user=current_user), help_text=''
    )
    class Meta(ReportFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['name']
```

And I don't know how can I get this user from other place. I've tried this:

```
class SiteFilter(BasicFilter):
    name = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "current_user" in kwargs:
            name = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
                queryset=MySiteModel.objects.filter(user=kwargs["current_user"]),
                help_text=''
            )

    class Meta(ReportFilter.Meta):
        fields = ['name']
```

And when I created this filter:
    site_filter = SiteFilter(current_user = "nickname")

But only what I've got, it is this:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_user'
```

Comment: is that your exact code that you ran when you got "unexpected keyword argument"?  you didn't call `super` in `__init__` ?

Comment: 1. Call parent __init__ in your constructor
2. Try to use kwargs.pop('current_user') before calling the parent __init__

Answer (score -1):

Look at your fields. Where are you expecting to plug in "current_user"? That doesn't look valid. I don't know filters well, but just from looking at your code, perhaps you want

```
site_filter = SiteFilter(name="nickname")
```